# In Azure Test Plans, how do you Move a Test Case to another Test Suite?

Tags: test-management, mtm, ms-azure, azure-devops, azure-test

In Microsoft Azure DevOps Test Plans / Test Manager, Test Plan view, how do you Move a Test Case to another Test Suite in the same Test Plan?

I am not able to drag and drop the test case to another suite in the same test plan like I was able to in Test Manager in TFS.

Clicking the "..." on the test case does not give the option to move the test case.

Under Test Case Define window, there is no option to move the test case or change the parent suite but there is an option to Add Related Work.

The [Microsoft Azure Dev Ops FAQ Website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops) does not give any info on moving a test case either

Added [Issue #62200](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6200) on Microsoft's Git Hub site requesting information

I submitted a New Request with [Microsoft Azure Support](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview).

Do you recommend asking Microsoft anywhere else?

[image]

Comment: Per the new test plans page help document (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/new-test-plans-page?view=azure-devops) the ability to drag and drop across suites is planned to be added, but no date has been listed. You can add a test case to a different test suite so it's linked to more than one test suite. I've not successfully removed a test case from a test suite yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the New Test Plans page @KatePaulk ! I haven't seen that yet! I wish Microsoft had better naming conventions, documentation, and versioning for all the implemented test plan management versions.

Comment: @KatePaulk could you please add a tag for Azure, Azure-DevOps, & Azure-Test-Plans for the new version of Microsoft Test Manager (tag MTM) on SQA Stack Exchange? The tag does not exist yet and should.

Comment: Brian - done. I have a very basic tag wiki entry for Azure, Azure-Devops and Azure-Test. I'll look to expand on those as time permits.

Comment: Thanks so much! This should be beneficial to everyone! :) @KatePaulk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Azure DevOps Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752133/cannot-drag-abd-drop-test-case-from-one-test-suite.html?inRegister=true), The Move or Drag & drop test case functionality is currently not available in new Azure Test Plans. It will be available in the coming weeks. For now, you can turn off the “New test plan page” preview feature to return to the old view by performing the following process:

1. Sign-in into your Azure DevOps Services organization
2. Click on your Avatar on the top right and navigate to "Preview Features"
3. Disable the 'New Test Plans Page' feature and navigate to Test Plans > Test Plans in your project of choice.

[image: azure devops test plans - move test case - remove preview test plan mode]

In the new Azure DevOps interface using the browser, there is not a copy procedure that will remove it from the original source Test Suite\Plan and place it into a different Test Suite Plan.   You have to first “Add” the Test Case to the target Test Suite,  then “Remove” the Test Case from any Test Suite where it is not desired. There are 2 ways to add existing Test Cases into a Test Suite\Plan:

[image: azure devops test plans - add existing test case 2]

[image: azure devops test plans - add existing test case 3]

Once you add the existing test case by query, can you remove the test case from it’s original location manually. When you select a test case, click the elipsis "..." then click remove. Note that a “Remove” does not imply a permanent deletion of the Test Case work item.  It only removes it from view of the Test Suite.

[image: azure devops test plans - remove test case from original suite]

Read more about the status of implementing the move or drag & drop test case feature at the [Azure DevOps Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752133/cannot-drag-abd-drop-test-case-from-one-test-suite.html?inRegister=true)

Answer (score 3):

for your information, the functionality of drag and drop is back, in the new interfaces the action is different between the tabs "Define" and "Execute", you need to be on "Define" tab to use drag and drop.